# How to parse a specific unregular table in python?

Tags: python, html, pandas, string, parsing

I am trying to parse [this example university timetable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UZkX.png) for quite some time now.

The biggest problem is how the data is presented here.

Every day is separated by `<tr>` with `<td>` inside attached to the first column. I have tried Pandas, but it gets confused by this and prints some weird table.

```
url = r'http://www.plan.uz.zgora.pl/grupy_plan.php?ID=23563'
tables = pd.read_html(url)
print(tables)
```

[Here is a link to this timetable](http://www.plan.uz.zgora.pl/grupy_plan.php?ID=23576) if someone is interested.

---

I have also tried converting it to JSON, but the data I got from it is really confusing to parse.
[Here, a link to Pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/5WqVh6yi)

I will be grateful for any solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum, tutorial, or code writing service. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: try `BeautifulSoup`

Comment: The answer to virtually all HTML parsing questions is `BeautifulSoup`.  It can return the pieces in a way that lets you do further processing.

Comment: @wwii I can't see how this post qualifies as a 'discussion forum thread', but thanks for the link. I will try to express the problems better in the future.
As for BS4 - I checked it out and it has done an amazing job! Thanks, Sean and Tim!

Comment: `read_html` is good for simple tables but for something more complex you need `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to parse `HTML`/`xml`. (PL: `read_html` jest dobre dla prostych tabel ale dla czegoś bardziej skomplikowanego potrzebujesz `BeautifulSoup` lub `lxml` aby parsować `HTML`/`xml`)

Comment: with `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` you could use `for`-loop to work with every row in table and use `class="gray"` to recognize row with day name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read_html()` is good for simple tables but for something more complex you need `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml` to parse `HTML`/`xml` and work with every element in `HTML`/`xml` (not only with text)

I use `BeautifulSoup` to find all rows in table, skip header and next I use `for`-loop to work with every row separatelly and check `class="gray"` to recognize row with day name.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.plan.uz.zgora.pl/grupy_plan.php?ID=23576'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = []      # list for data from all rows

dayname = ''   # string with current day name 

# get all rows from table
all_rows = soup.find('table', {'id': 'table_groups'}).find_all('tr')

for row in all_rows[1:]:   # `[1:]` to skip header

    if 'gray' in row.get('class'):
        dayname = row.text.strip()
        print('DAY NAME:', dayname)
    else: 
        cols = row.find_all('td')  # get all columns in row
        cols = [x.text.strip() for x in cols]  # get text from all columns
        
        print('     Dzień:', dayname)
        print('        PG:', cols[0])
        print('        Od:', cols[1])
        print('        Do:', cols[2])
        print(' Przedmiot:', cols[3])
        print('        RZ:', cols[4])
        print('Nauczyciel:', cols[5])
        print('   Miejsce:', cols[6])
        print('   Terminy:', cols[7])
        
        cols.insert(0, dayname)  # add day name to row as first column
        data.append(cols)  # keep row on list

    print('---')
```

Result:

```
DAY NAME: Poniedziałek
---
     Dzień: Poniedziałek
        PG: 
        Od: 07:35
        Do: 09:00
 Przedmiot: Technika eksperymentu
        RZ: W
Nauczyciel: dr hab. inż. Ryszard Rybski, prof. UZ
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: DI
---
     Dzień: Poniedziałek
        PG: 
        Od: 09:15
        Do: 10:45
 Przedmiot: Analiza danych
        RZ: W
Nauczyciel: prof. dr hab. inż. Dariusz Uciński
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
     Dzień: Poniedziałek
        PG: A
        Od: 11:00
        Do: 12:30
 Przedmiot: Programowanie obiektowe
        RZ: L
Nauczyciel: dr inż. Paweł Majdzik
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
     Dzień: Poniedziałek
        PG: B
        Od: 12:45
        Do: 14:15
 Przedmiot: Programowanie obiektowe
        RZ: L
Nauczyciel: dr inż. Paweł Majdzik
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
DAY NAME: Wtorek
---
     Dzień: Wtorek
        PG: 
        Od: 09:15
        Do: 10:45
 Przedmiot: Teoretyczne podstawy informatyki
        RZ: W
Nauczyciel: prof. dr hab. inż. Andrzej Obuchowicz
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
     Dzień: Wtorek
        PG: 
        Od: 11:00
        Do: 12:30
 Przedmiot: Teoretyczne podstawy informatyki
        RZ: Ć
Nauczyciel: prof. dr hab. inż. Andrzej Obuchowicz
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
     Dzień: Wtorek
        PG: 
        Od: 12:45
        Do: 14:20
 Przedmiot: Podstawy systemów dyskretnych
        RZ: Ć
Nauczyciel: prof. dr hab. Roman Gielerak
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: DN
---
     Dzień: Wtorek
        PG: 
        Od: 14:30
        Do: 16:00
 Przedmiot: Podstawy systemów dyskretnych
        RZ: W
Nauczyciel: prof. dr hab. Roman Gielerak
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
DAY NAME: Środa
---
     Dzień: Środa
        PG: 
        Od: 07:35
        Do: 09:00
 Przedmiot: Fizyka
        RZ: W
Nauczyciel: dr Stefan Jerzyniak
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: DP
---
     Dzień: Środa
        PG: B
        Od: 09:15
        Do: 10:45
 Przedmiot: Analiza danych
        RZ: L
Nauczyciel: dr hab. inż. Andrzej Janczak, prof. UZ
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
     Dzień: Środa
        PG: A
        Od: 11:00
        Do: 12:30
 Przedmiot: Analiza danych
        RZ: L
Nauczyciel: dr hab. inż. Andrzej Janczak, prof. UZ
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
     Dzień: Środa
        PG: 
        Od: 12:45
        Do: 14:15
 Przedmiot: Programowanie obiektowe
        RZ: W
Nauczyciel: dr inż. Paweł Majdzik
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
     Dzień: Środa
        PG: A
        Od: 15:50
        Do: 17:25
 Przedmiot: Podstawy systemów dyskretnych
        RZ: L
Nauczyciel: mgr inż. Mariusz Downar
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: DN
---
     Dzień: Środa
        PG: B
        Od: 19:05
        Do: 20:40
 Przedmiot: Podstawy systemów dyskretnych
        RZ: L
Nauczyciel: mgr inż. Mariusz Downar
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: DN
---
DAY NAME: Czwartek
---
     Dzień: Czwartek
        PG: A
        Od: 07:45
        Do: 10:00
 Przedmiot: Technika eksperymentu
        RZ: L
Nauczyciel: dr hab. inż. Sergiusz Sienkowski, prof. UZ
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: 2021-03-04; 2021-03-11; 2021-03-18; 2021-03-25; 2021-04-08; 2021-04-15; 2021-04-22; 2021-04-29; 2021-05-06; 2021-05-13
---
     Dzień: Czwartek
        PG: 
        Od: 11:00
        Do: 12:30
 Przedmiot: Fizyka
        RZ: Ć
Nauczyciel: dr Krzysztof Maciesiak
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
---
     Dzień: Czwartek
        PG: B
        Od: 12:45
        Do: 15:00
 Przedmiot: Technika eksperymentu
        RZ: L
Nauczyciel: dr hab. inż. Sergiusz Sienkowski, prof. UZ
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: 2021-03-04; 2021-03-11; 2021-03-18; 2021-03-25; 2021-04-08; 2021-04-15; 2021-04-22; 2021-04-29; 2021-05-06; 2021-05-13
---
DAY NAME: Piątek
---
     Dzień: Piątek
        PG: 
        Od: 09:15
        Do: 10:45
 Przedmiot: Wprowadzenie do sieci komputerowych
        RZ: W
Nauczyciel: dr hab. inż. Marcin Mrugalski, prof. UZ
   Miejsce: 
   Terminy: D
```

You can use `pandas` to save it as `csv` or `json`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Dzień', 'PG', 'Od', 'Do', 'Przedmiot', 'RZ', 'Nauczyciel', 'Miejsce', 'Terminy'])
print(df)

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
df.to_json('output.json', orient='records', indent=2, force_ascii=False)

print(df.to_json(orient='records', indent=2, force_ascii=False))
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "Dzień":"Poniedziałek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"07:30",
    "Do":"09:00",
    "Przedmiot":"Seminarium dyplomowe I",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"prof. dr hab. inż. Krzysztof Patan",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Poniedziałek",
    "PG":"B",
    "Od":"09:15",
    "Do":"10:45",
    "Przedmiot":"Seminarium dyplomowe I",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"prof. dr hab. inż. Krzysztof Patan",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Poniedziałek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"09:15",
    "Do":"12:15",
    "Przedmiot":"Projekt grupowy",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Anna Pławiak-Mowna",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Poniedziałek",
    "PG":"B",
    "Od":"11:00",
    "Do":"12:30",
    "Przedmiot":"Testowanie i rozwój aplikacji",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Jacek Bieganowski",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Poniedziałek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"12:45",
    "Do":"14:15",
    "Przedmiot":"Testowanie i rozwój aplikacji",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Jacek Bieganowski",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Poniedziałek",
    "PG":"B",
    "Od":"12:45",
    "Do":"14:20",
    "Przedmiot":"Platforma.NET",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Marek Sawerwain",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"DN"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Wtorek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"07:30",
    "Do":"12:30",
    "Przedmiot":"Język angielski IV\/Język niemiecki IV",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"mgr Jolanta Bąk",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Wtorek",
    "PG":"B",
    "Od":"07:30",
    "Do":"12:30",
    "Przedmiot":"Język angielski IV\/Język niemiecki IV",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"mgr Jolanta Bąk",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Środa",
    "PG":"",
    "Od":"07:30",
    "Do":"09:05",
    "Przedmiot":"Projektowanie sieci komputerowych",
    "RZ":"W",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr hab. inż. Bartłomiej Sulikowski, prof. UZ",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"DN"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Środa",
    "PG":"",
    "Od":"07:35",
    "Do":"09:00",
    "Przedmiot":"Testowanie i rozwój aplikacji",
    "RZ":"W",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Jacek Bieganowski; dr inż. Michał Doligalski",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"DP"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Środa",
    "PG":"B",
    "Od":"09:15",
    "Do":"10:45",
    "Przedmiot":"Projektowanie sieci komputerowych",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"mgr inż. Marcin Pazera",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Środa",
    "PG":"",
    "Od":"11:00",
    "Do":"12:30",
    "Przedmiot":"Platforma.NET",
    "RZ":"W",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Marek Sawerwain",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Środa",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"12:45",
    "Do":"14:15",
    "Przedmiot":"Projektowanie sieci komputerowych",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"mgr inż. Marcin Pazera",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Środa",
    "PG":"B",
    "Od":"12:45",
    "Do":"14:15",
    "Przedmiot":"Platforma.NET",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Marek Sawerwain",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Czwartek",
    "PG":"B",
    "Od":"12:10",
    "Do":"15:10",
    "Przedmiot":"Projekt grupowy",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Małgorzata Mazurkiewicz",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Piątek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"07:30",
    "Do":"09:00",
    "Przedmiot":"Platforma.NET",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"mgr inż. Mariusz Downar",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"2021-04-09; 2021-04-16; 2021-04-23; 2021-04-30; 2021-05-07; 2021-05-14; 2021-05-21; 2021-05-28; 2021-06-04; 2021-06-11; 2021-06-18"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Piątek",
    "PG":"",
    "Od":"09:30",
    "Do":"11:00",
    "Przedmiot":"Programowanie urządzeń mobilnych",
    "RZ":"W",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Piotr Powroźnik",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Piątek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"11:10",
    "Do":"11:55",
    "Przedmiot":"Programowanie urządzeń mobilnych",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Piotr Powroźnik",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Piątek",
    "PG":"B",
    "Od":"12:05",
    "Do":"12:50",
    "Przedmiot":"Programowanie urządzeń mobilnych",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"dr inż. Piotr Powroźnik",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"D"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Piątek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"14:20",
    "Do":"15:50",
    "Przedmiot":"Platforma.NET",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"mgr inż. Mariusz Downar",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"2021-04-09; 2021-04-16; 2021-04-23"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Piątek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"14:20",
    "Do":"15:50",
    "Przedmiot":"Platforma.NET",
    "RZ":"L",
    "Nauczyciel":"mgr inż. Mariusz Downar",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"2021-05-14; 2021-05-28; 2021-06-11; 2021-06-18"
  },
  {
    "Dzień":"Piątek",
    "PG":"A",
    "Od":"16:00",
    "Do":"18:15",
    "Przedmiot":"Platforma.NET",
    "RZ":"P",
    "Nauczyciel":"mgr inż. Mariusz Downar",
    "Miejsce":"",
    "Terminy":"2021-05-28; 2021-06-11; 2021-06-18"
  }
]
```

---

Code needs some code to get `Miejsce` and `Google Classroom` in `Przedmiot`

Comment: That's one really impressive answer, thank you for that!

Comment: some of my answers I keep on GitHub: [python-examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/)